# Button display : inline doesn't break line

Tags: html, css, button

I want my buttons to display inline and break line inside of them like spans

See fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ojkvdyfL/

```css
.container{
    width:400px;
}
.subcontainer{
    display: inline;
}
button{
  display: inline;
  all:unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>1st example with buttons</p>
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <button> This is a short text in buttons </button>
        <button>with a longer text next to it because we need it so it takes mutliple lines to illustrate this issue</button>
    </div>
    <p>2nd example with spans</p>
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <span>This is a short text in spans </span>
        <span>with a longer text next to it becaufdsse we need it so it takes mutliple lines to illustrate this issue</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not understand why the button example does not work like the span one...

The inline spec says : "In normal flow, the next element will be on the same line if there is space."

Any idea why it's not working ? Does a CSS solution exists? Or do i have to use spans with role="button"?

Comment: Actually, you are using span with width and button has default full width

Comment: I edited to make it more clear (width was ignored anyway because of inline)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Can't you see that both examples display differently despite the only difference is button replaced by span? Maybe you know why a button with full css reset and display: inline doesn't act like a span? (I removed !important to avoid debates on this...)

Comment: @user1372445 sorry - I missed totally the issue on mobile. I see now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 spec does not allow a button to be rendered like that, [Button Layout](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#button-layout) says

> ... if the computed value of 'display' is a value such that the outer display type is 'inline', then behave as 'inline-block'."

it's done for backward compatibility with the days when button rendering was delegated to an O/S function.

Comment: Interresting, thank you for this answer. I guess i'll need to use spans for now then ;)

Comment: Phew that was tricky to find. Thanks for the answer!